# Force ngx_pagespeed to use png8

Tags: nginx, page-speed

I used ngx_pagespeed to optimize my web server with Nginx. One of the servers is an image reverse proxy that supposed to fetch images from a remote server, optimize it, and send back to the client. However, most of the remote image is already optimized under PNG24 so pagespeed will just drop it with `image_rewrites_dropped_nosaving_noresize` count increased by one. If I manually optimize such image with PNG8, it will save a lot without really hurting my images, in my case.

Is there a way to force ngx_pagespeed to optimize with PNG8 or any other parameters I can try? Note lossless compression is not a requirement for my case. I also tried converting to webP but didn't gain too much.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered in stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704069/force-ngx-pagespeed-to-use-png8

The short answer is that it does not support such conversion yet.